# My post just got heavily downvoted, but I think it was a good question; now what?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently had an issue that I have been struggling to track down for quite some time. It's somewhat sporadic and I haven't been able to reproduce it, but I was able to get a core and track it down sufficiently (I thought) to get some community support:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41363635/double-free-or-corruption-when-writing-to-log-from-multiple-threads

Given the nature of the error I think it might be a bug in the boost library itself, so this error might (or might not) be experienced by others as well.

My post does not isolate a reproducible program that causes the bug, but it shows the exact lines of code where the bug occurs.

My post got multiple down-votes and is about to be put on hold, and the reasons given by commenters are not overly helpful. I'm not really sure what to do next - normally I would take on the advice of the comments, but in this case I'm not sure that's practical (I don't know what exactly the advise *is*).

Any advice?

Comment: Ouch. That could fire back badly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what do you mean?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ah right, well, what else can I do? Your comments are not helpful and nor are those of others. I also think you're wrong in downvoting my question. I don't see what I have to lose.

Comment: @arman: "*what else can I do*" You could do as commenters suggest and *post the code you're having problems with*.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ also, I've had some success seeking MSO support in the past. This question for example was heavily downvoted before I posted on MSO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321237/how-can-boost-be-used-to-achieve-c14-style-auto-return-types. Sometimes the initial response is just wrong.

Comment: I think the original question did get lynched. I don't think it's a perfect question as it lacks information but the number of downvotes it received is not proportional to its quality. Much worse questions have positive vote count all over SO while this queston is being voted into oblivion.

Comment: @NicolBolas I've already explained, both here and in the original post, why I can't provide a reproducible example. I can't just repeat it ad nauseum...

Comment: And I'm sure part of what πάντα ῥεῖ meant, besides invoking the meta effect, is your choice of words on this meta question. Don't know if you are a native to the USA, but one of your words can be construed as being not appropriate to use in mixed company to describe a question going badly.

Comment: @patricksweeney I am not from the USA, we use that word pretty liberally where I'm from, but thanks I wasn't aware of that - will change.

Comment: @patricksweeney I have replaced it with equally dramatic, but less controversial wording.

Comment: The title still implies too much emotion, there's nothing "savage" about the downvotes, one person cannot savage your question by giving you a single downvote. If many people are giving you downvotes, then that is community concensus.

Comment: Agreed it's still overly dramatic, but it's a ton better than what was there.

Comment: I have reduced both the drama and political connotations of the title.

Comment: Again, you are getting overly emotional about this.

Comment: @DavidG I was trying to make a joke - that was the wording I originally used but removed because patrick suggested it might be offensive.

Comment: Well you can perhaps understand that it doesn't seem that way to the rest of us?

Comment: @xxbbcc: You cannot compare DV rations of different questions, because they are DVed by different people and even the same people will have different scales when to DV on different days. I'd say all less than -3 shows the question is not well recepted. Similarily, some ppl seem to upvote by reflex only once a post contains (halfway) correct english, no matter it's contents.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When asked to provide a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, you said:

> I can't. I am unable to provide a verifiable example. If I could, I would just isolate and fix the problem myself.

Well... what do you expect *us* to be able to do about it? We cannot *remotely* debug the problem. We cannot *magically* know what's going on.

If you cannot isolate the problem to an MCVE, then *we cannot help you*.

Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. It's certainly not a *telepathic* debugging service.

Comment: I don't understand the limitation you are placing on SO questions; does this mean we can't ask questions that we cannot reproduce in a minimal example?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP understands this. In some cases, it may be impossible to provide an MCVE and yet the question may still be useful, even if no one can give an actual solution that will directly apply to resolve the problem.

Comment: @arman: Pretty much. If the problem is with a bug in a piece of code, and you cannot narrow that code down to a reasonably-sized piece of code, then the only thing we can do is *guess* at what the problem *might* be. "Guessing" is not what SO is for.

Comment: @xxbbcc: "*In some cases, it may be impossible to provide an MCVE and yet the question may still be useful, even if no one can give an actual solution that will directly apply to resolve the problem.*" How is a question with no answers useful? Again, SO is not about us playing *guessing games* about what the problem *might* be.

Comment: You are correct: you cannot ask question of the form "why is my code not working" without providing a minimal, complete, verifiable example. There are only two ways of coming up with an answer to such a question: 1. a bug that's obvious simply by looking at what's shown in the question 2. reproducing the bug yourself. Unless the bug is obvious just by looking at the shown code, a [mcve] is required to answer the question. This question falls into the latter category.

Comment: @NicolBolas I understand your point - what I'm trying to point out is that this question is downvoted into the low negatives while it's a very realistic scenario that some developers have to face regularly. Some problems are inherently guessing games (because of complexity, scale, etc.) and SO was very useful in the past in these situation, as long as the poster and answerers all understand that a clear answer won't emerge. I myself had similar issues in the past with complex, heavily parallel code and ideas on SO helped a lot.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I was hoping it would fall into the former.

Comment: It's not. There's nothing obvious in the grand total of two lines of the shown code. And, as I pointed out, just because a C++ program crashes at a particular line doesn't mean that's where the bug is. It shouldn't take me more than a few minutes to write a simple demonstration of a bug stomping on the stack, but the function continuing to execute until it returns, and until it's caller return, and ***then*** the second `return` crashes. But that won't be where the bug is, obviously. Your bug can be anywhere in your code.

Comment: So utterly disappointing you don't do *telepathic debugging*. Given the high-demand I expect a healthy business model is hidden in there ...

Comment: @xxbbcc there is no such thing as "too" downvoted. If it's bad, you downvote. You shouldn't go "oooh it's bad but shouldn't be at -5". You should vote on the merit of the post, regardless of current score, rep of poster, etc. And remember we are there for long lasting answers. The scenario you describe is pretty much everything stack isn't meant to be...

Comment: @arman Consider that SO isn't the right tool for *every possible problem.* Some problems simply cannot be solved in the format of something like SO. In this case it appears some very in-depth debugging sessions are the only thing that can really help you.

Comment: @deceze yeah but in this case I was hoping the community could point out whether there's an obvious issue with my usage or a bug with the library itself. It seems like everyone got way too hung up on the fact that the problem wasn't reproducible, that they ruined a good opportunity to provide a helpful answer to a common problem. I will go back and try to reproduce the issue as you said - but it's disappointing because someone with more knowledge than me on this topic could have saved me (and others) a lot of time.

Comment: If it was an obvious bug with the library, whatever research you did to isolate your issue and figure out how to solve it would have exposed the existence of such a bug.... It seems to me like you took a risk: either the bug is obvious and someone will point it out, or the bug isn't obvious. If it's the latter, then your question isn't to the quality standards here. You took a risk.... It backfired.

Comment: @arman Your problem simply doesn't look like it's at the stage where you can fire off a question to a broad audience just yet, it's too vague and undefined. If you can actually narrow it down to a specific library/function call with a minimal example which you can post and say for certain that this will sooner or later produce the problem if you let it run as is, then it's ready to be presented to the general public. Until then you're asking for a decentralised outsourced debugging session, for which SO doesn't work. Try the chat maybe for such a thing.

Comment: @deceze I have shown the exact function call that causes this problem, the backtrace, and the types involved, as well as a snippet from the documentation outlining why I think my usage is correct. Obviously others agree with your comment but I don't understand what it is that made you (and others) say that the problem is too vague?

Comment: @deceze I'll give the chat a go - I hadn't thought of that. Cheers.

Comment: @arman: "*I have shown the exact function call that causes this problem*" No, you have shown the function where the problem *manifests*. That's not the same thing. If your car's breaks are broken, you go through a red light, and knock a truck into a restaurant, the problem is not that the restaurant was in the way of the truck.

Comment: @arman Can you write a short program from scratch which contains only that one function call (and whatever boilerplate is necessary) which behaves as your describe? Then please present it and it's a great question. Otherwise it could possibly be a million other things interfering.

Comment: @deceze no I can't do that. I guess you're right - this is just a bad problem to be asking about here.

Comment: @arman what makes the problem too vague is it's vagueness.... I have SOME knowledge of boost. Never saw or heard of such an issue. It looks like the problem is in your code,and isolating it will help you figure it out. Without ANYTHING to reproduce the bug, I am left with the 'lemme throw 70 theories at the wall and see which one sticks'. Stack isn't for that.

Comment: @Patrice yeah you're probably right.

Comment: @arman and honestly, I havebeen in your situation (my only deleted question is about a weird c# bug I faced and was just unable to figure out) and it truly sucks.... But try to see Stack as ONE of your tools to get help. It's a very specialized tool, so it only helps in specific circumstances :). Good luck with the bug hunting though :).